# Displaying HTML Code Blocks

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a site that has code examples (in HTML,JavaScript,CSS,etc) and need to figure out how to display the code without the browser interpreting it as anything but text.

I wrote a JavaScript function to convert the <, > from the text, and then it writes the result, but the browser still seems to recognize < /script > (without the spaces before and after /script.

```
        function codeToHTML(input) {
            var output = "";
            for(i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
                var c = input.charAt(i);
                if(c=='<') {
                    output+="&lt;";
                } else if (c=='>') {
                    output+="&gt;"; 
                } else if (c=='\n') {
                    output+="<br>";
                } else if (c==' ') {
                    output+="&nbsp;";
                } else {
                    output+=c;
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I think that the problem is that I hard coded the code to be converted in a var before running the function, and that the browser still reacts to the < /script > from the definition. How should I store the code such that the browser doesn't try to execute it?

Comment: At the server's side, you can encode the text. If the data is generated client-side, you can use `element.textContent = '<br>';` which is equivalent to `element.innerHTML = '&lt;br&gt;';`. Another thing to try is to put the code in `CDATA` sections, then let the script read this and output it using `.textContent`.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 has a pretty useful `<code>` tag function where everything you put in it will display as code format. You can also use the `<pre>` tag so it displays it exactly how you want it.

If you are talking about specifically handling special characters, I guess you could write some js for that but if they are gonna be static examples, I think it'd be easier to just simply backslash them and/or write their appropriate codes as you did in your javascript. If you think about it, the thing that makes the script run is when it sees a `<script>` tag. Get rid of that, and it knows not to run it so just do `&ltscript&gt` It sounds annoying but I think it'll be a lot less of a hassle in the long run. Ideally your HTML should be focused on the content and I would say displaying the code is a content thing, and not a Javascript thing.

If you are dealing with mountains of code, you can also just use a [HTML converter](http://web.forret.com/tools/html.asp). Hope this helps.

Comment: LOL this is embarassing. I didn't know until recently ><